# Permission denied when trying to forward ports in openshift

Tags: debugging, database-connection, openshift, portforwarding, openshift-client-tools

I am kinda new to openshift and I am trying to give it a try.
While following [this](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift) tutorial when running the rhc port-forward -a command. I am getting an Permission Denied error. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

The problem is not the password. If you enter a wrong password you get a different error message

Thank

```
C:\development\infra\appServer\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\bin>rhc port-forward -a <My WebApp>
Password: *****

Checking available ports...
Forwarding ports
C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.6.3/lib/net/ssh/service/forward.rb:68:in `initialize': Permission denied - bind(2) (Errno::EAC
CES)
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.6.3/lib/net/ssh/service/forward.rb:68:in `new'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.6.3/lib/net/ssh/service/forward.rb:68:in `local'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.2.7/lib/rhc/commands/port-forward.rb:133:in `block (3 levels) in run'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.2.7/lib/rhc/commands/port-forward.rb:127:in `each'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.2.7/lib/rhc/commands/port-forward.rb:127:in `block (2 levels) in run'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.6.3/lib/net/ssh.rb:193:in `start'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.2.7/lib/rhc/commands/port-forward.rb:125:in `block in run'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.6.3/lib/net/ssh.rb:193:in `start'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.2.7/lib/rhc/commands/port-forward.rb:88:in `run'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.2.7/lib/rhc/commands.rb:138:in `block (3 levels) in to_commander'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:402:in `run_active_command'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.2.7/lib/rhc/command_runner.rb:54:in `run!'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/delegates.rb:11:in `run!'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.2.7/lib/rhc/cli.rb:40:in `start'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.2.7/bin/rhc:21:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
        from C:/development/infra/buildtools/RubyInstaller193/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're running an older version of the rhc client tools (1.2.7).  Please try it again after updating your client tools (gem update rhc).

The error indicates that your host can't bind a particular local port possibly cause it's in use.  The latest rhc client responds by binding to the next open port.  Let us know if you're still having issues after updating.

Comment: I am on latest rhc, but it still didn't work for me!

Comment: try to use `rhc setup`. It must be a ssh key issue. This command will help you to upload and update the key